# Programmatically start GPSD daemon in linux

Tags: linux, debian, daemon, startup, gpsd

I am doing a project read GPS values output from a GPS dongle and need to 
programmatically start the gpsd daemon.

i.e. I need to automate the following command;
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock

I was able to read the coordinates through the code after manually starting the daemon as above. But don't know how to start the daemon through he code.

Comment: Avoid using `sudo` from inside a program. Maybe you might configure your `udev` to stard the daemon when the dongle is plugged in or activated.

Comment: actually, that is what i need to know...how to configure to start the daemon when the dongle is plugged

Comment: Study carefully the documentation of `udev` ....

Comment: and then tell the rest of us ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since gpsd is a daemon, you can just set the daemon up to be run automatically at startup. How to do this depends on which startup system you have. For example, if you have systemd, you have to write a *gpsd.service* file, something like this

```
[Unit]
Description=GPSd daemon service file

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
Group=dialout
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock


[Install]
# Grouping mechanism that let systemd start groups of processes up at the same time
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then install it in `/lib/systemd/system` and finally using the following commands

```
$ sudo systemctl enable gpsd
$ sudo systemctl start gpsd
```

the start command is just to run gpsd as systemd daemon without rebooting your system.

Answer (score 1):

for debian its just

```
dpkg-reconfigure gps
```